# Got System.InvalidOperationException: Method failed with unexpected error code 64

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, console-application, file-security

I am working on getting folder's permission before access in `C#` console application , the path of folder could be local of ftp.Same is working on my machine but when deploy at production server its start throwing error `System.InvalidOperationException: Method failed with unexpected error code 64`.

The exact error receive by code is

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Method failed with unexpected error code   64.
at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)
at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemSecurity..ctor(Boolean isContainer, String name, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean isDirectory)
at System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity..ctor(String name, AccessControlSections includeSections)
at UploadData.FolderManager.IsConfiguredFolderAccessible(String path, Folder folder)
```

The full code that thrown error is

```
 private static void IsConfiguredFolderAccessible(string path, Folder folder)
    {
        // If the file can be opened for exclusive access it means that the file
        // is no longer locked by another process.
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                LogHelper.Log(string.Format("Folder does not exist on given path {0}. Please re-create folder, grant permission and re-start the UPC utility. ", folder.Path), LogHelper.LogLevel.Error);
                MailComponent.SendMail(string.Format("Folder does not exist on given path {0}. Please re-create folder, grant permission and re-start the UPC utility.", folder.Path), "Folder does not exist");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var accessControlList = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);

                if (accessControlList == null)
                {
                    LogHelper.Log(string.Format("AccessControlList on Folder {0} are not defined", folder.ToString()), LogHelper.LogLevel.Error);
                    MailComponent.SendMail(folder.ToString(), "AccessControlList on Folder are not defined");
                }
                var accessRules = accessControlList.GetAccessRules(true, true,
                                            typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));

                if (accessRules == null)
                {
                    LogHelper.Log(string.Format("AccessRules on Folder {0} are not defined", folder.ToString()), LogHelper.LogLevel.Error);
                    MailComponent.SendMail(folder.ToString(), "AccessRules on Folder are not defined");
                }
                foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in accessRules)
                {
                    if ((FileSystemRights.Write & rule.FileSystemRights) != FileSystemRights.Write)
                        continue;

                    if (rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Deny)
                    {
                        LogHelper.Log(string.Format("Access permission denied on Folder {0}", path), LogHelper.LogLevel.Error);
                        MailComponent.SendMail(folder.ToString(), string.Format("Access permission denied on Folder {0}", path));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (PrivilegeNotHeldException pv)
        {
            LogHelper.Log(string.Format("Access permission denied on Folder {0}, Error detail : {1}", path, pv.ToString()), LogHelper.LogLevel.Error);
            MailComponent.SendMail(pv.ToString(), string.Format("Access permission denied on Folder {0}", path));
            throw pv;
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            LogHelper.Log(string.Format("Folder does not exist on given path {0}, Error detail : {1}", path, io.ToString()), LogHelper.LogLevel.Error);
            MailComponent.SendMail(io.ToString(), string.Format("Folder does not exist on given path {0}.Please re-create folder, grant permission and re-start the UPC utility.", path));
            throw io;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.Log(string.Format("General error occured on Folder {0}, Error detail : {1}", path, ex.ToString()), LogHelper.LogLevel.Error);
            MailComponent.SendMail(ex.ToString(), "General error occured");
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7006001). I hope this'll help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is generated by a call to the native Windows `GetSecurityInfo()` function. You can see this in the source code for the [`NativeObjectSecurity`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/accesscontrol/nativeobjectsecurity.cs,07f3bea4f932c637) class. Error 64 or 0x40 in hex has the following definition in [`winerror.h`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx):

> `ERROR_NETNAME_DELETED`
>
> The specified network name is no longer available.

So your problem is most likely related to accessing a folder across the network.

Comment: So how can i managed that error, ideally it should caught and logged in log file.

Comment: @NeerajDubey: You have lots of exception handling in your code. Expand on that and catch `InvalidOperationException`. If you specificially wants to handle "error 64" you will have to parse the exception message. In the reference source I linked you can see how the exceptions are thrown. However, depending on the specifics of the .NET source code will create a tight coupling between your code and something that is outside your control.